# Converting key-values of python dictionary into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I've a python dictionary with single or multiple integer values as string like :

```
d = {'a': ['1.20', '1', '1.10'], 'b': ['5.800', '1', '2.000'], 'c': ['9.5000', '0.9000'], 'h': ['1.90000', '6.100000'], 'l': ['1.0000', '8.00000'], 'o': '5.0000', 'p': ['3.00', '1.1000'],  'v': ['1.8', '0.0000']}
```

How to convert it into a pandas DataFrame **without taking help of pandas series?**

Expected Output :

```
            col1  col2  col3
       a    1.2   1     1.1
       b    5.8   1     2
       c    9.5   0.9   NaN
       h    1.9   6.1   NaN
       l    1     8     NaN
       o    5     NaN   NaN
       p    3     1.1   NaN
       v    1.8   0     NaN
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use helper `Series`:

```
df = pd.concat({k:pd.Series(v) for k, v in d.items()}).unstack().astype(float).sort_index()
df.columns = 'col1  col2  col3'.split()
```

Another solution is convert not list values to one element list and then [`DataFrame.from_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html):

```
d = {k:v if isinstance(v, list) else [v] for k, v in d.items()}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').astype(float).sort_index()
df.columns = 'col1  col2  col3'.split()


print (df)
   col1  col2  col3
a   1.2   1.0   1.1
b   5.8   1.0   2.0
c   9.5   0.9   NaN
h   1.9   6.1   NaN
l   1.0   8.0   NaN
o   5.0   NaN   NaN
p   3.0   1.1   NaN
v   1.8   0.0   NaN
```

Comment: Small point: you either have to sort by index or use ordered dictionary for expected output.

Comment: In the above example how do i add a header for the key too?

Comment: @SoubhikBanerjee - Do you think `df.columns = 'col1  col2  col3'.split()` ?

Comment: @jezrael This columns are the for the values right? in the above example for key a we have three values which we are splitting into col1,2 and 3. But my question is how do i add header for the key i.e. 'a' in this case too?

Comment: @SoubhikBanerjee - You need `df = df.rename_axis('Name')`

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

d = {'a': ['1.20', '1', '1.10'], 'b': ['5.800', '1', '2.000'],
     'c': ['9.5000', '0.9000'], 'h': ['1.90000', '6.100000'],
     'l': ['1.0000', '8.00000'], 'o': '5.0000', 'p': ['3.00', '1.1000'],
     'v': ['1.8', '0.0000']}

# convert to numeric
for k, v in d.items():
    lst = list(map(float, v)) if isinstance(v, list) else [float(v)]
    lst += [np.nan] * (3 - len(lst))
    d[k] = lst

# sort dictionary by key & create cols
d = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items()))
cols = list(zip(*d.values()))

# build dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d).T

#      0    1    2
# a  1.2  1.0  1.1
# b  5.8  1.0  2.0
# c  9.5  0.9  NaN
# h  1.9  6.1  NaN
# l  1.0  8.0  NaN
# o  5.0  NaN  NaN
# p  3.0  1.1  NaN
# v  1.8  0.0  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

TRy

```
df = pd.Series(d).apply(pd.Series).rename(columns=lambda col: 'col{}'.format(col+1))
```

the output will be

```
      col1      col2   col3
a     1.20         1   1.10
b    5.800         1  2.000
c   9.5000    0.9000    NaN
h  1.90000  6.100000    NaN
l   1.0000   8.00000    NaN
o   5.0000       NaN    NaN
p     3.00    1.1000    NaN
v      1.8    0.0000    NaN
```

Without pd.Series

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(map(lambda v: [v] if type(v)!=list else v,d.values())
   ),index=d.keys(),columns=['col{}'.format(col+1) for col in range(3)])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also maybe want to first pad all the values of your dict to length-3 arrays

```
padded_d = {k : list(v) + [None] * (3 - len(v)) for k,v in d.items()}
```

And then use the `.from_dict()` of `pd.DataFrame()`

```
>>> pd.DataFrame.from_dict(padded_d, orient="index")

    0   1   2
a   1.20    1   1.10
b   5.800   1   2.000
c   9.5000  0.9000  None
h   1.90000 6.100000    None
l   1.0000  8.00000 None
p   3.00    1.1000  None
v   1.8 0.0000  None
```

---

To cope with your ill-formatted value for key `'o': '5.0000'` (we expect `'o' : ['5.0000']` - not sure if that was a typo though) in your input , you should check the type... Although that could be cleaner

```
def type_check(s):
    if isinstance(s, str):
        return [s]
    else:
        return s

padded_d = {k : type_check(v) + [None] * (3 - len(v)) for k,v in d.items()}
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(padded_d, orient="index")
```